# How to find parts of Regular expression - integers?

Tags: javascript, regex

When I try to receive 3 part of regexp but if string is not completely equal to regular expression it returns an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`.

How I can receive each part of regexp in one attempt

```
var str = this.value;
var da = str.match(/(\+7)(\d{3})(\d{3})/);
var newStr = da[1] + "(" + da[2] + ")" + da[3];
```

How I can receive da[1] if str == +7 and da[2] if str == +7 922 without error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the second capture group with `?` to make it optional:

```
var da = str.match(/(\+7)(\d{3})?/);
// -----------------------------^
```

Then for the string `"+7"`, the match will succeed, `da[1]` will be `+7`, and `da[2]` will be `undefined`.

**Update**: And similarly for the third capture group you've added to the question. :-)

Comment: I love the comment. +1 for clarity